# LDAP not returning all attributes

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, adam, adlds

I'm using Ldap to retrieve accounts from AD LDS:

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=adminuser,o=myorg,c=uk");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://myldapserver:636");
InitialLdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);

SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
controls.setReturningAttributes(null);
    // according to javadoc, null means "return all attributes"

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results =
    context.search(userBase, "cn=SOMEUSER", controls);
```

The account comes back fine.  But not all of SOMEUSER's attributes get returned.

Specifcally, the `msDS-UserPasswordExpired` attribute never comes back.

---

However... if I list that attribute in `SearchControls`:

```
controls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] {
    "msDS-UserPasswordExpired", "cn", "mail"
});
```

Then magically it **does** come back.

Why?  Is `SearchControl` javadoc lying?

How do I tell it that I *really* **really** want **all** attributes back?

The workaround is to list every single attribute that I want back.  But that's hideous, and will make adding future fields very error-prone.

Comment: have you tried by removing the setRetuningAttributes(null) line from your code.

Comment: @Shriram It wouldn't make any difference. That's the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password-control attributes are operational attributes, which aren't returned unless you specifically ask for them.

> How do I tell it that I really really want all attributes back?

You specify `new String[]{"*", "+"}` as the attribute IDs to return: `"*"` means all non-operational attributes, and `"+"` means all operational attributes. But this is not generally a good idea. There are lots of operational attributes that are none of your business. Just ask for what you actually need.

Comment: Even if we use * then its not returning that value. All others are coming. How to use * with that value simultaneously ?

Comment: @Anand_5050 That's because you didn't do what it says in my answer.

Comment: Is this correct? Should it be: "*" means all non-operational attributes, and "+" means all operational attributes